# how to read entirety of pipe

Tags: c, linux

I am working on a program where the main program forks itself and the child process calls exec. I have set it up so that the parent process has 2 pipes `StdOutPipe` and `StdInPipe`, and the child process calls dup so that `stdout` writes to the `StdOutPipe` and `stdin` reads from `StdInPipe`. Then the parent process calls wait, after which i would like to read the entirety of the StdOutPipe into a buffer. I know you can do so by reading one character at a time, but is there a faster way to do so?

Comment: Read more than one character at a time? There is no such thing as "read the rest of the pipe" because you always have to read it into a buffer of a given size. So it's up to you how big you want to make that buffer and that is the size that you can use in each read call until the read returns 0 or -1.

Comment: A pipe has a finite capacity, usually 64 KiB these days.  You will have to make multiple calls to `read()` if there is more data to be read.  You may have to make multiple calls to get all the data even if the total amount is less than the pipe capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance reasons, one typically reads a chunk at a time, not a character at a time.

1. Loop,

   1. Attempt to enlarge the buffer so it can fit CHUNK_SIZE more bytes.
   2. If an error occurred,

      1. Fail.
   3. Attempt to read CHUNK_SIZE bytes from the pipe into the unused part of the buffer.
   4. If an error occurred,

      1. Fail.
   5. If EOF was reached,

      1. Break.
   6. Increased the total number of bytes read by the number of bytes read.

Comment: how big typically is CHUNK_SIZE?

Comment: However big you want it to be, @JadenAmatuzzo.   You could sensibly use a multiple of 1024 bytes — probably a power of 2, so 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536.  Bigger than 64 KiB is probably not sensible.

Answer (score 0):

A pipe is basically a byte stream which means:

1. There's no concept of messages or message boundaries with pipes
2. The process reading from a
   pipe can read blocks of data of any size, regardless of the size of blocks written by
   the writing process

A read from a pipe is usually blocked until atleast a byte is written to the pipe.

That said, here's how i would implement your issue.

1. Create two pipes, stdinpipe and stdoutpipe
2. Do a fork
3. Parent process should close the write end of the pipes and sit in a
   loop, waiting until data is written to pipe
4. Child process should close the read end of the pipes and duplicate
   STDOUT to stdoutpipe and STDIN to stdinpipe
5. Child process can then do an exec.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define STDPIPE_BUFFER_SIZE 4096
#define ARGV_SIZE 3

int main()
{

    // Stdoutpipe and stdint pipe
    int stdoutpipe[2], stdinpipe[2], stdin_char_count, stdout_char_count, stdout_read, stdin_read;
    pid_t pid;
    char stdinbuffer[STDPIPE_BUFFER_SIZE], stdoutbuffer[STDPIPE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *argv[ARGV_SIZE]; // arguments to exec

    if (pipe(stdinpipe) == -1 || pipe(stdoutpipe) == -1)
        exit(1); // error occurred

    // Fork and exec

    switch (pid = fork())
    {
    case -1:
        exit(1); // error
    case 0:

        // child close the read end of both pipes

        if (close(stdinpipe[0]) == -1 || close(stdoutpipe[0]) == -1)
            exit(1);

        // have the pipes as the new STDIN and STDOUT
        if (dup2(stdinpipe[1], STDIN_FILENO) == -1 || dup2(stdoutpipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1)
            exit(1);

        argv[0] = "/usr/bin/ssh"; // replace with your own program [ssh -V  in my case]
        argv[1] = "-V";
        argv[2] = NULL;

        execve(argv[0], argv, NULL);
        exit(1); // if we get here something horribly bad happened

    default:
        // parent process
        stdin_char_count = 0;
        stdout_char_count = 0;
        // parent close write end of both pipes
        if (close(stdinpipe[1]) == -1 || close(stdoutpipe[1]) == -1)
            exit(1);

        for (;;)
        {
            stdin_read = read(stdinpipe[0], stdinbuffer, STDPIPE_BUFFER_SIZE);
            stdout_read = read(stdinpipe[0], stdinbuffer, STDPIPE_BUFFER_SIZE);

            if (stdin_read == 0 && stdout_read == 0)
            {
                stdinbuffer[stdin_char_count] = '\0';
                stdoutbuffer[stdout_char_count] = '\0';
                break;
            }

            if (stdin_read == -1 && stdout_read == -1)
                exit(1); // we cant recover from this
                
            stdin_char_count += stdin_read;
            stdout_char_count += stdout_read;
        }
        printf("%s\n", stdoutbuffer);
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

source: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the pipe into an ordinary stream and then use whatever function you find convenient to read the data. Here, `getdelim()` can be used to read all text up to a NUL byte which need not be sent over the pipe. Error checking is partially omitted for brevity.

Also be aware that if you want to continue interacting directly with the pipe even after opening the stream, you'll probably want to disable buffering on the stream.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int fds[2];
    if(pipe(fds) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to create pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    const pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == -1) {
        perror("Failed to fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(!pid) {
        close(fds[0]);
        const char *const msg = "Hello, world!";
        if(write(fds[1], msg, strlen(msg)) == -1) {
            perror("Failed to write");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    close(fds[1]);
    FILE *const stream = fdopen(fds[0], "r");
    if(!stream) {
        perror("Failed to create stream");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *text = NULL;
    assert(wait(NULL) != -1);
    getdelim(&text, &(size_t){0}, '\0', stream);
    fclose(stream);

    assert(text);
    puts(text);
    free(text);
}
```